# Error accessing Views after copying site to another server

Tags: views, 8

I inherited an out of date Drupal 8 site, and have been tasked with extracting some data for import into another location. I thought I would create a View to query the data that I'm after, and then work to export it.

When I navigate to `http://localhost/admin/structure/views`, I get the following error:

`The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</br></br><em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityMalformedException</em>: The &quot;view&quot; entity cannot have a URI as it does not have an ID in <em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase-&gt;toUrl()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">191</em> of <em class="placeholder">core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase.php</em>).`

Other pages that I have tested on the site load correctly.

I have migrated the site by copying the entire directory structure and the database to my local machine, updated settings.php to reflect the local database. I cleared caches and am able to log in and navigate to a large sample of pages successfully.

Some searching on this particular error doesn't seem to get me too far, except to some references of other modules (not Views).

Help?

Comment: Can you load the Extend page (modules list)? Anything on Status Report? Can you save the modules list form? Tried updating Drupal? May be relevant: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2018-01-06/the-website-encountered-an-unexpected-error-please-try

Comment: If the database in locally works then it should work on server too, Try to import the local database to server and see. I think this issue seems like some modules are removed without uninstalling it. So it might be not reflected in the database.